# Truffle migration script does not make transaction

Tags: truffle

Please look at my simple example below. Is migration script 3 being executed, such that it sets the value on the blockchain -- I think not, because there is no speak about a txHash or cost...

How to make truffle do a transaction for migration script 3.

contracts/Test.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.5.8;

contract Test {

    uint256 c; 

    function read() public view returns ( uint256 ) {
      return c;
    }

    function write( uint256 _c ) public {
      c = _c;
    } 
}
```

Migrations scripts

```
$ cat migrations/1_initial_migration.js 
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

```
$ cat migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js 
var Test = artifacts.require("Test");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Test);
};
```

```
$ cat migrations/3_set.js 
var Test = artifacts.require("Test");

module.exports = function(deployer) {

  Test.deployed().then( t => {
    t.write(1)
  })

};
```

Truffle output

```
truffle migrate --network goerli 

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Test.sol
> Artifacts written to test_sc/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'goerli'
> Network id:      5
> Block gas limit: 0x7a1200


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x778fd1772305c7425141ed0bd871e59c5c95ea07ac3e608dd40c7bdb30d8b3e1
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 12
   > contract address:    0x44f40AAFF065A1bAf4d9Dd204e22B5C419F1DC8f
   > block number:        1210809
   > block timestamp:     1567180517
   > account:             0x1ae222dCbEEC5c581F44d8bCC87e74fcfAB083Cb
   > balance:             0.063013755
   > gas used:            261393
   > gas price:           5 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.001306965 ETH

   Pausing for 2 confirmations...
   ------------------------------
   > confirmation number: 1 (block: 1210810)
   > confirmation number: 2 (block: 1210811)

   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:         0.001306965 ETH


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Deploying 'Test'
   ----------------
   > transaction hash:    0x2a1cd709be9eaf1fefba8382a3e6c0a825fca72555beca76b4acdf868556996d
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 12
   > contract address:    0x74BdaE85cC50E3554Ae16cC7d09a83dAe503Ca41
   > block number:        1210813
   > block timestamp:     1567180577
   > account:             0x1ae222dCbEEC5c581F44d8bCC87e74fcfAB083Cb
   > balance:             0.062278565
   > gas used:            105015
   > gas price:           5 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.000525075 ETH

   Pausing for 2 confirmations...
   ------------------------------
   > confirmation number: 1 (block: 1210814)
   > confirmation number: 2 (block: 1210815)

   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:         0.000525075 ETH


3_set.js
========

   > Saving migration to chain.
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:                   0 ETH
```

Look at that last line, didn't do it.

Comment: Change `t => {t.write(1)}` to `async (t) => {await t.write(1)}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem with your third script is that `deployed()` is async and you are not waiting for it to finish. Wrapping it in an async function and awaiting should make it work.

```
var Test = artifacts.require("Test");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.then(async () => {
    const t = await Test.deployed();
    await t.write(1);
    console.log('Completed!');
  });
};
```

The other problem is that Truffle does not track operations that are not contract deployments. Even if the call has succeeded it will appear as it used 0 eth.

The console.log at the end will show a message if the transaction was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Tou should do this in the second migration script, like:

```
var Test = artifacts.require("Test");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Test).then( (instance) => 
    instance.write(1);
)};
```

`deploy` function returns the contract instance (`truffle-contract` object). So, call its function after it is deployed.

P.S. This won't be shown in the console, but you can see tx on etherscan.